# Best approach for XAML game

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am developing a board game with a grid. Every grid has some options for the end user. The idea is that an options menu will be displayed under the grid when the user clicks a grid cell. My XAML looks like:

Mainpage.xaml:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="450"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <game:Board Grid.Row="0"/> 
     <game:Chooser Grid.Row="1" d:IsHidden="False"/>
</Grid>
```

The Board is a grid which contains a square object in each cell. Each square object does have MouseLeftButtonDown listener. When clicking the square object, the chooser menu must open and some parameters must be passed to this object.

What would be the best approach to do this as the chooser is a member of another class? Do I need to pass the chooser object (which is in MainPage.xaml) to the board and square object? Or is there a way to propagate the event to the chooser?

Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 1):

I would do three things:

- First, have each board tile all raise the same custom RoutedEvent
  (called something like "Chosen, which has been defined on a base
  class "Tile").
- Second, have the Board listen for the Tile.Chosen event. Once the
  board sees the event, have it set a new property
  "ChosenTile"/"ChosenTileInfo"/or whatever it is you need.
- Lastly, create a DependencyObject on the Chooser control (it would be
  called something like "Target"), so that you could bind it to
  ChosenTile.

The code above would end up looking something like:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="450"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <game:Board Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MyBoard"/> 
     <game:Chooser Grid.Row="1" Target="{Binding ChosenTile, ElementName=MyBoard}"/>
</Grid>
```

---

The other option is to still do the first part, but instead of creating a DependencyObject, just raise your own event and do everything else in code-behind.